# Host an angular project on localhost and allow access from a different network?

Tags: angular, typescript, server, web-hosting

This might be a dumb question, I know nothing about cybersecurity and I'm rather new to web development, but is it possible to host a angular project on localhost and allow anyone with my public ip address to access it?

I tried `ng serve --disable-host-check` and `ng serve --public-host 0.0.0.0` they both seem to only allow access from a local network. Is there a way to do this so that my collegue can access the website by using `mypublicipaddress:4200`?

Comment: Do you mean in development mode? or after you're done development?

Comment: during development

Comment: I don't remember doing anything special when I did that in the past. All I did was, after running `ng serve`, asked a colleague to access my `MY.PUBLIC.IP.ADDRESS:4200`. If it's not working, perhaps it's a restriction on your firewall.

Comment: I also think it might have something to do with your router's firewall. How are you connecting to the internet. Usually whether you are connecting through a home's wireless network or behind a corporate gateway, your device doesn't have its own IP address, rather it uses some kind of NAT or PAT. In which case, you'd have to configure the gateway server to forward http requests to your device.

Comment: thanks! yeah im at home, does this mean ill have to change the configuration of the router?

Answer (score 1):

The next command works for me

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

then type the local ip address into another device, e.g.

```
192.168.1.80:4200
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to export your ip adress in public network